# SDL.Net application not working without SDL.NET SDK

Tags: installation, sdl, sdl.net

I have a game that I have made in C# and it installs and runs as expected under Windows XP.  However when I install it on a Windows 7 machine, then it either simply doesn't work (without any error message) or it gives a generic error message.  Is there anything special that I have to do in order to be able to use SDL.Net with a Windows 7 computer?

UPDATE:  I have just been informed that it doesn't even work on XP.  Both XP machines I tried it on had SDL.NET installed (I didn't know that one of them already had it when I used it for testing).  So pretty much if SDL.NET SDK is not installed on a computer my program doesn't work.  Does anyone have some insight into what exactly needs to accompany my program from SDL in order to make it work properly?  right now I have all the base SDL_*.dll and SdlDotNet.dll and Tao.Sdl.dll.  More needed?  Or is there some kind of SDL runtime that I have to install with my program in order to use it?  I am really stuck with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added every Dll including those that weren't explicitly needed and it now works.  Apparently there are some hidden links between dll's that I didn't know about.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it as admin? I don't mean happening to be logged in as an admin account, I mean right click the exe and Run As Administrator? If you do that and don't get the error, then your problem will be quite easily solved, without requiring it to always Run As Admin.

Comment: Tried that out to no avail as well.  I really have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: So you are looking for differences between Win7 and XP other than UAC. My next bet would be paths. Did you hard code any file paths like Documents and Settings\...  ?

Comment: I updated my initial post with the new info that I got.  Thanks for trying to help